# Visual Studio Code's Intellisense does not recognize npm-installed package

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I recently began studying NodeJS using VSCode, and it turns out that Intellisense does recognize the methods of core Node modules (fs, http, os etc.), but not those belonging to an npm module which I installed by myself, using the `npm install` command (the pack: [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)).

When chained with `.default`, however, Intellisense does accurately provide the methods belonging to the package.

Has anyone else encountered this issue when working with VSCode and NPM?

[image]

Comment: i have the same issue... is there an answer ?